# Disable printing of stracktrace/ BuildException output in STS Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle

At present I am running Gradle 2.x/3.x builds via Eclipse Neo and an [STS Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle). If there is a problem while building, e.g. in the compileJava Task I get a detailed information of what is wrong (imo printed to stderr in the console tab of eclipse and then also a kind of stacktrace for the build exception that occured (imo printed to stdoutin the console tab).

Here is an example output:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      compileJava
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[...]
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or  --debug option to get more log output.
[sts] Build failed
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-bin.zip'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at org.[...]
```

The stacktrace comes along with **[sts]** so I think it is not directly from Gradle. Is there a way to suppress printing of the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradle STS build plugin does not provide a way to disable this stack trace printing.
This can be verified by looking at [how this stack trace printing is implemented in the plugin source](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/c82613863a53573e123793a18545f178edef9b7c/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core/src/org/springsource/ide/eclipse/gradle/core/TaskUtil.java#L127).
All output is sent to the same printstream, there is no logging framework or configuration options that would allow for granular control of what is printed.
It is worth noting that this plugin has been deprecated (and is being minimally maintained) in favour of the [buildship plugin](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship).
The buildship plugin does not exhibit the same stack trace printing behaviour.